# How to display URL on facebook messenger via IBM WATSON Chatbot?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, facebook-chatbot

The issue is on IBM Watson bluemix console the output is proper.It is displaying URL and images fine.But on FB messenger it is displaying whole **href** tag and also the image is not visible.

**OUTPUT :**

ON IBM CONSOLE : `This is a link Google`

ON FB MESSENGER:`This is a link <a  target="_blank" href= "https://google.com">Google</a>.`

How to hide the `<a  target="_blank" href= "https://google.com">Google</a>` whole tag on FB ?

**OUTPUT IMAGE:**
[*ON IBM BLUEMIX CONSOLE*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcOje.png)

[*ON FB MESSENGER*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rINXX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Messenger automatically turns a url string into a link for the user to click on.

So simply remove the HTML tags, and pass the url in the message.

> "This is a link to Google: **www.google.com**"

If you don't want to expose the url, you can also use [**Facebook Messenger Buttons**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/buttons).